# Processing within Eclipse: initializing a Client

Tags: eclipse, ide, client, processing

I am working on a Processing program within Eclipse and I am having issues initializing the Client object. I have properly imported both **core.jar** and **net.jar** from the Processing package into my class from these locations:

C:\Program Files\eclipse\processing-2.0.2\core\library
C:\Program Files\eclipse\processing-2.0.2\modes\java\libraries\net\library\net.jar

```
public class Client extends PApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    // Declare a client
    Client client;

    public void setup() {
        size(400, 200);

        // create the client
        client = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
    }
}
```

The line Eclipse is complaining about (**client = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 8888)** shows an error: the constructor Client(Client, String, int) is undefined.

Per the Client API, there is a constructor that takes those arguments: http://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Client.html.

I have also tried **client = new Client(this, 8888);** and Eclipse is still complaining about an error. Can anyone help guide me on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is called `Client` so the `new Client` in your code is trying to create an instance of your class. What you actually want is an instance of `processing.net.Client`. It would be best to use a different name for you class:

```
import processing.net.Client;

public class MyApplet extends PApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    // Declare a client
    Client client;

    public void setup() {
        size(400, 200);

        // create the client
        client = new Client(this, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
    }
}
```

I have changed the class name to `MyApplet`.